# Protecting ASP.NET authentication cookie from moving to another computer

Tags: asp.net, security

How to protect asp.net authentication cookie from moving to another computer? I mean to avoid illegal access to the system.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Cookies do not "move".

Comment: If hacker has physical access to computer and he stole cookie by coping

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent a hacker from sniffing (by air, or by wire-tapping) the authentication cookie and using it on another computer, you have to ensure that you serve your website using https, rather than http.